# instagram 7.13 not working with arc welder on acer chromebook 11 - shows error / puzzle piece?

Tags: apk, automatic-ref-counting, instagram, google-chrome-arc

I tried crossy roads but it doesn't work.

I was able to get holocalc to work but this is a very simple app. Am I missing something or is instagram (the one I really care about) not compatible with ARC welder?